# Laravel Pass HTML Variable to EMail view

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to add option that users can manually edit what text they want to see in e-mail. I have added field where you can add the text and I want to make that you can add variables in that text, so when it loads from database and puts that in the e-mail view it shows the value of variable not {{ $variable }} in email.

Now I have done this

```
                        $date = new DateTime();
                    $date->modify('+' . $vakance2->uzdevuma_laiks . ' days');
                    // Izveido praktikanta vardu un uzvardu
                    $name = $praktikants2->vards . " " . $praktikants2->uzvards; 
                    $vakances_epasts = $vakance2->vakance_approve_email;
                    // Masivs kas tiek nosutits 'emails.kval' vai 'emails.nokval' lapai
                    $data = array('vakances_epasts' => $vakances_epasts, 'name' => $name, 'vakance' => $vakance2->vakances_nosaukums, 'secret_key' => $praktikants2->secret_key, 'date' => $date, 'uzdevums' => $vakance2->uzdevuma_teksts);
                    // Vakances uzdevuma atrasanas vieta        
                    $pathToFile = public_path() . "/uploads/uzdevums/" . $vakance2->uzdevuma_fails;
                    // Epasta nosaukums
                    $title = "Pieteikums vakancei - " . $vakance2->vakances_nosaukums;
                    // Praktikanta epasts
                    $epasts = $praktikants2->epasts;
                    //Pārbauda vai praktikants ir piesaistīts esošajai vakancei
                    if($praktikants2->vakances_id == $vakance->id) {
                        // Parbauda vai praktikanta koeficients ir lielaks par vakances noteikto, lai kvalificētos tālāk. Ja ir tiek izmainīts ierakts tabulā 'praktikanti' ieraksts 'otra_karta' uz 1, ka praktikants ir kvalificējies. Ja nē tas paliek 0
                       if($praktikants2->koeficients > $vakance->koeficients_kval) {
                            $praktikants2->otra_karta = "1";

                            // Tiek nosutits epasts
                            Mail::send('emails.kval', $data, function($message) use ($pathToFile, $title, $name) {

                                $message->attach($pathToFile);
                               // $title = "Pieteikums vakancei";
                                $message->to('naurislinde@gmail.com', $name)->subject($title);

                                //$message->attach($pathToFile);


                            });
                        } else {

                            // Tiek nosutits epasts
                            Mail::send('emails.nokval', $data, function($message) use($title, $name)
                            {
                                //$title = "Pieteikums vakancei";
                                $message->to('naurislinde@gmail.com', $name)->subject($title);
                            });
                        }
                        $praktikants2->save();
                    }
```

And the view is

```
{{ $vakances_epasts }}
```

And this is the code saved in database, which users can edit

```
Sveicināts - {{ $name }} Jūs esat kvalificējies otrajai kārtai vakancē   {{   $vakance }}.
 <br><br><br>
  Apmeklējiet <a href="http://localhost:8000/uzdevums/{{ $secret_key }}">šo</a> lapu, lai apstiprinātu uzdevumu. Uzdevuma nodošanas laiks ir {{    $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T') }}
  <br><br>
  Uzdevums: {{ $uzdevums }}
```

But when I send the e-mail it shows exactly like that.

Sveicināts - {{ $name }} Jūs esat kvalificējies otrajai kārtai vakancē {{ $vakance }}.  Apmeklējiet [šo](http://localhost:8000/uzdevums/%7B%7B%20$secret_key%20%7D%7D) lapu, lai apstiprinātu uzdevumu. Uzdevuma nodošanas laiks ir {{ $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T') }} 
 Uzdevums: {{ $uzdevums }}

Comment: whats the file name of the email, is is 'name.blade.php' sounds like the 'blade' is missin form the filename

Comment: It's kval.blade.php and nokval.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$vakances_epasts` is not parsed via Blade. Instead, it's treated as a string, ergo your message prints as it appears in the database - without replacing the variables.

I recommend parsing the string using a custom algorithm. You could use a simple string replace for the particular variable names.

```
$string = 'Hello {{ $bar }}';
$value = 'world';
$string = str_replace('{{ $bar }}', $value, $string);
echo $string; // Hello world
```

Once you have parsed the `$string` yourself, pass it to your view and it should work as you are expecting.

*Tip:* You could separate the work into multiple classes which you can pipe the string through. Making it easier to maintain a clean syntax and organise the logic. A similar approach was used to create the generators in Jeffrey Way's [Laravel 5 Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) package.